# Setting ngModel dynamically

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular-ngmodel, two-way-binding

I am trying to build a basic Polling App which has the fields as shown in the image.
[image: This is the view of the app.]
[image: The template of the App.]
[image: The ts file for the component. I haven't written any kinda logic in this file just logging out the value of the form.]
[image: As I enter value for the first field the second field also gets updated with the same value. How can I achieve two way binding in this case?]

Since there are fields for two inputs i want binding for each field(Option 1 & Option 2 as option1 and option2 respectively so i can reference it in the ts file.)
But when I type option for the first field the second field also gets the same value & likewise for the second field. How can I set two way binding for each of the input field?

After I click on Create Poll button the console displays as:
        {
          "question": "Who will win World Cup?",
          "option1": "Germany",
          "option2": "Germany"
        }

Comment: @TheHeadRush No problem sir. Next time I post a question I will try my best to meet the standards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your index:

```
[(ngModel)]="options[i]"
```

and create an option array in the component

Answer (score 2):

You can simply have an array of options instead of a simple variable option, and use this in your template :

```
count = [1, 2];
options: string[2];
```

...

```
[(ngModel)]="options[i]"
```

options[0] has the first one, options[1] has the second